# A Lexicographical Bug in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Please take this question lightly as asked from curiosity:

**As** I was trying to see how the slicing in MultiIndex works, I came across the following situation ↓

```
# Simple MultiIndex Creation
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'c', 'b'], [1, 2]])

# Making Series with that MultiIndex
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=6), index=index)
```

Returns:

```
a  1    5
   2    0
c  1    8
   2    6
b  1    6
   2    3
dtype: int32
```

**NOTE** that the indices are ***not*** in the sorted order ie. `a, c, b` is the order which will result in the ***expected*** error that we want while slicing.

```
# When we do slicing
data.loc["a":"c"]
```

Errors like:

```
UnsortedIndexError

----> 1 data.loc["a":"c"]
UnsortedIndexError: 'Key length (1) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'
```

That's expected. But now, after doing the following steps:

```
# Making a DataFrame
data = data.unstack()

# Redindexing - to unsort the indices like before
data = data.reindex(["a", "c", "b"])

# Which looks like 
   1  2
a  5  0
c  8  6
b  6  3

# Then again making series
data = data.stack()

# Reindex Again!
data = data.reindex(["a", "c", "b"], level=0)


# Which looks like before
a  1    5
   2    0
c  1    8
   2    6
b  1    6
   2    3
dtype: int32
```

#### The Problem

So, now the process is: `Series → Unstack → DataFrame → Stack → Series`

Now, if I do the slicing like before *(still on with the indices unsorted)* we **don't get any error!**

```
# The same slicing
data.loc["a":"c"]
```

Results without an error:

```
a  1    5
   2    0
c  1    8
   2    6
dtype: int32
```

**Even if** the `data.index.is_monotonic` → `False`. Then still why can we slice?

So the question is: **WHY?**.

> I hope you got the understanding of the situation here. Because see, the same series which was before giving the error, after the `unstack` and `stack` operation is not giving any error.

So is that a bug, or a new concept that I am missing here?

Thanks!
Aayush ∞ Shah

**UPDATE**:
I have used the `data.reindex()` so to unsort that once more. Please have a look at it again.

Comment: stack/unstack implicitly sorts the data, which is what MultiIndex loves, and wont give you any performance issues

Comment: @sammywemmy Great, sorts the data — but what after stacking? I tried redinexing. I unsorted data once more after the stack operation, which well doesn't return any error!

Comment: sorry, didnt get that. Do you mind updating your question with the new scenario?

Comment: @sammywemmy Please consider the `reindex` steps even after unstack and stack operation. Unsorting after stack and unstack. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I get your point now. if you play with the error code a bit, you'll notice a `_lexsort_depth` attribute. The first time, without any stack/unstack/reindex drama, the depth is 0, and the length of the tuple (the Multindex values) is 1, and it fails. However, it seems after the unstack drama, the depth now becomes a 2, and as such the if condition is not executed. Not sure why that is the case. is it a bug? maybe ... Maybe you can dig further, or raise an issue on Pandas github page?

Comment: @sammywemmy is right. You have to look also to `index.codes` to really understand how the data is indexed internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between your 2 dataframes is the following:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'c', 'b'], [1, 2]])

data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=6), index=index)

data2 = data.unstack().reindex(["a", "c", "b"]).stack()

>>> data.index.codes
FrozenList([[0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

>>> data2.index.codes
FrozenList([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Even if your two indexes are the same appearance (values), the internal index (codes) are differents.

Check [this method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/87b8a6ea06f649c3659afc8f896357da5197567c/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L1867) of `MultiIndex`:

```
        Create a new MultiIndex from the current to monotonically sorted
        items IN the levels. This does not actually make the entire MultiIndex
        monotonic, JUST the levels.

        The resulting MultiIndex will have the same outward
        appearance, meaning the same .values and ordering. It will also
        be .equals() to the original.
```

---

**Old answer**

```
# Making a DataFrame
data = data.unstack()

# Which looks like         # <- WRONG
   1  2                    #    1  2
a  5  0                    # a  8  0
c  8  6                    # b  4  1
b  6  3                    # c  7  6

# Then again making series
data = data.stack()

# Which looks like before  # <- WRONG
a  1    5                  # a  1    2
   2    0                  #    2    1
c  1    8                  # b  1    0
   2    6                  #    2    1
b  1    6                  # c  1    3
   2    3                  #    2    9
dtype: int32
```

If you want to use slicing, you have to check if the index is monotonic:

```
# Simple MultiIndex Creation
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'c', 'b'], [1, 2]])

# Making Series with that MultiIndex
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=6), index=index)

>>> data.index.is_monotonic
False

>>> data.unstack().stack().index.is_monotonic
True

>>> data.sort_index().index.is_monotonic
True
```

Comment: Please have a look at my steps: I used `.reindex()` there so the index becomes unsorted. The step I missed before :)

Comment: @AayushShah. I updated my answer and found the problem. It's not a bug. There is a difference between what you see and what is stored internally.

Comment: nice detective work @Corralien. new knowledge unlocked for me. once an index is sorted, the information is stored(cached) and potentially reused. thanks

Comment: I already had UV you, (although here the solution are quite different)